# How to create a dynamic view based on the input from a user in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

For example, I have to create a view for a particular employee which stores the attendance information for the last 50 days and I have over a milion employees.

I will be giving the employee id as the input and I want this view to be created only for this employee with the last 50 days of his attendance details.

A simplistic explanation will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than creating separate views for each employee, couldn't you link the currently connected user account to an employee ID somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is just a stored query. Therefore, if you always need only the last 50 days, then

```
create or replace view v_50 as
select empno, ename, date_in, date_out
from attendance
where date_in >= trunc(sysdate) - 50
```

Then fetch data for any employee you need:

```
select *
from v_50
where empno = 1234;
```

On the other hand, you don't need a view for this at all - do the same from the original table:

```
select empno, ename, date_in, date_out
from attendance
where empno = 1234
  and date_in >= trunc(sysdate) - 50
```

Make sure that both `empno` and `date_in` are indexed, regularly gather statistics.

---

To retrieve data for specific month, one option is to

```
select ...
from attendance
where to_char(date_in, 'yyyymm') = '202009'
```

A function-based index would help; otherwise, you'd have to use something like

```
where date_in between date '2020-09-01' and date '2020-03-30'
```

if `date_in` is indexed, as `to_char`-ing it wouldn't be able to use such an index.

Comment: If I want take for particular month by giving an input, how can I do it??

Comment: I added some more info; have a look.